# 2012se w/remote web access, reverse proxy not working:err 502.3

Tags: php, iis, proxy, calibre

I have 2012se v1 with remote web access set up so that `http://localhost = https://tirnanog.remotewebaccess.com`
Using IIS 8

I want to set up the Calibre OPDS server so that https://tirnanog.remotewebaccess.com/calibre will launch the PHP based site.

http://blog.slucas.fr/en/oss/calibre-opds-php-server

I installed reverse proxy pieces and PHP based on the We Got Served new eBooks for 2012se.
No matter what I try, accessing anything in the calibre directory gives me HTTP error 502.3 bad gateway.

I've tried putting the calibre site both in a physical directory under the default Web site and in a virtual directory with the physical directory in C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\WebApps\Site

No difference.
I do have the COPS site working on my Win8.1 Pro machine just fine.
SO its something with remote web access and reverse proxy/url rewrite

Any help appreciated.
thnx
-RickH

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.
I posted the full steps for 2012SE, which should work for recent MS OS's.
http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=170903

Password protected, works fine in browsers and OPDS capable readers.
Even works on my Kindle II experimental browser.